# Netlogo: plot update without adding new X axis values

Tags: netlogo

So I'm doing a program where agents have a certain life value and I want to make a plot about it.

- In the X axis is the ID of the agent.
- In the Y axis is the life of the agent.

The problem I have is that in every tick of execution it creates a new X axis value and I only want to update Y values without adding X.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you really want to do this by ID?  Some kind of histogram looks to be more useful.  (See the Histogram Example in the NetLogo models library.)

Answer (score 2):

While you should definitely check out Alan's suggestion, you can use [`plotxy`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plotxy) to do what you're asking:

```
ask turtles [
  plotxy id life
]
```

where `id` and `life` are the variables you want to use for x and y. That is, if you're just using `who` numbers as for your ids, you'd do `plotxy  who life`. But yeah, do checkout Alan's suggestion.